# Is it possible to make this div move smoothly?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this `div` move smoothly while changing colors, but the problem is that right before it should transition into the `#bad455` color, it stops briefly.

So I was wondering are there any ways to make it go smoothly without no stopping?

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: anim1;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    background-color: pink;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bad455;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: use `linear` as timing function, the default one is `ease`

Answer (score 1):

You set the iteration count to infinite so your animation keeps going and set the margin of your last keyframe back to 0 so it returns to it's default state.

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div:hover {
  animation-name: anim1;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    background-color: pink;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bad455;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your div tag:

```
 -webkit-transition: width 2s; 
    transition: width 2s;
```